# Default parameters for methods of template class

Tags: c++, templates, default-parameters

Is there a way to provide default parameter values for methods of a template class? For example I have the following:

```
template<class T>
class A
{
public:
    A foo(T t);
};
```

How should I modify this to give `foo` a default parameter of type `T`? For example: `T` is `int` then a default value of -23, or `T` is `char*` then default value of `"something"`, etc. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the default parameter to be just the default value (zero, usually), then you can write `A foo(T t = T())`. Otherwise, I suggest a trait class:

```
template <typename T> struct MyDefaults
{
  static const T value = T();
};

template <> struct MyDefaults<int>
{
  static const int value = -23;
};


template<class T>
class A
{
public:
    A foo(T t = MyDefaults<T>::value);
};
```

Writing the constant value inside the class definition only works for integral types, I believe, so you may have to write it outside for all other types:

```
template <> struct MyDefaults<double>
{
  static const double value;
};
const double MyDefaults<double>::value = -1.5;

template <> struct MyDefaults<const char *>
{
  static const char * const value;
};
const char * const MyDefaults<const char *>::value = "Hello World";
```

In C++11, you could alternatively say `static constexpr T value = T();` to make the template work for non-integral values, provided that `T` has a default constructor that is declared `constexpr`:

```
template <typename T> struct MyDefaults
{
  static constexpr T value = T();
};

template <> struct MyDefaults<const char *>
{
  static constexpr const char * value = "Hello World";
};
```

Comment: You could also make value be a static member function.